# I created free space and I don't know to recover it

Tags: disk-utility, disk-format, diskutil

So I followed this answer here
[Merge partitions with Macintosh HD](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235568/merge-partitions-with-macintosh-hd)

And I ended formatting my old bootcamp partition into free space.
But now I am unable to see the free space anywhere. When I go to disk utility it just says that I am using 200 GB of storage even though I have 256 GB with 50 GB just gone, somewhere.

Diskutil cs list
Shows nothing

[image]

Comment: What do you see if you right click your drive and select "Get Info".  A window should pop up telling you disk size and space available.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to enter the following commands in a Terminal application window. The first command removes the OSXRESERVED partition. This partition is for the Windows installation files. The second command expands the `disk1` container to consumer the missing free space.

```
sudo  diskutil  erasevolume  free  none  disk0s3
sudo  diskutil  apfs  resizecontainer  disk0s2  0
```