# Diskutil how to merge unaccessible partition

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I have my main partition, `disk0s2`, which needs to be enlarged because I am out of memory. My SSD is of 480 GB capacity and is split in many partitions. The ones that I try to merge to the main one (`disk0s2`) are `disk0s6` and `disk1s1`(which was `disk0s5` before but somehow I managed to send it to `disk1 (synthesized)` using the `eraseVolume` command.

How can I merge `disk0s6` and `disk1s1` to the main partition (`disk0s2`)? I also tried to do it in **Partition** window in **Disk Utilty** but it didn't allow me to perform any operations.

Here is the diskutil list result:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *480.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         195.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:           Linux Filesystem                         54.4 GB    disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data OSXRESERVED             8.0 GB     disk0s4
   5:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                93.3 GB    disk0s6

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +195.7 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            187.5 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 42.0 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                512.4 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      3.1 GB     disk1s4
```

And a ss from **Partition** in **Disk Utility**:[image]

I have managed to merge the last two, this is my situation now:

[image]

The diskutil list result:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *480.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         195.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:           Linux Filesystem                         54.4 GB    disk0s3
   4:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         228.5 GB   disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +228.5 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s4
   1:                APFS Volume OSXRESERVED             938.0 KB   disk1s1

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +195.7 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            187.0 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 42.0 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                512.4 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      3.1 GB     disk2s4
```

Can I apply the solution presented here? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/235580/353022

Comment: You are confused. `disk1s1` is already inside the container `disk0s2`. You can not enlarge `disk0s2` to include the space occupied by `disk0s6` unless you also include the space occupied by `disk0s3` and `disk0s4`. I assume the missing 128.49 GB was occupied by `disk0s5` and is now free space due to your use of the `diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s5` command.

Comment: When you wrote ***"How can I merge `disk0s2` and `disk1s1` to the main partition (`disk0s2`)?"***, did you mean ***"How can I merge `disk0s6` and `disk1s1` to the main partition (`disk0s2`)?"***?

Comment: @DavidAnderson yes, that's what I meant, sorry for the mistake

Comment: @DavidAnderson yes, for the first question, it was occupied by `disk0s5` before

Comment: @DavidAnderson I now see that you've given the solution in the link above as well (the one I edited just now). Is that applicable to my case (add the free space from disk0s4 to disk0s2)?

Comment: Are you willing to delete the linux partition (`disk0s3`)? It is either that, or find some third party tool that can relocate (move) a linux partition.

Comment: @DavidAnderson is there anything you would recommend for the third party tool?